# When run RSpec I get uninitialized constant Name::Name::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I constantly get this error when try to run my specs from root path:

```
Failure/Error: routes { MyEngineName::Engine.routes }

NameError:
     uninitialized constant MyEngineName::MyEngineName::Engine
```

And either when run server from spec/dummy and goes to localhost:3000 the same happens but with the `MyEngineName::MyEngineName::ApplicationController`

In tests I need to declare where routes are from:

```
require 'rails_helper'

module MyEngineName
  module Companies
    RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
      routes { MyEngineName::Engine.routes }
      render_views

      # ommited... 
    end
  end
end
```

And my engine file is:

```
# my_engine_name/engine.rb
module MyEngineName
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngineName
    engine_name 'my_engine_name'

    # ommited...
  end
end
```

what can I do?

Thanks in advice! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fully qualified name in your spec instead of placing your specs in a module.

Do:

```
RSpec.describe Foo::Bar::Baz do

end
```

Don't:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    RSpec.describe Baz do

    end
  end 
end
```

Besides the fact that writing specs at 3 levels of indentation is ugly as heck you're asking for a kick in the privates by changing the context as it will try to resolve everything from the `Foo` namespace so that you have to use `::SomeOtherModule` to refer to everything else.

Comment: Conceptually you should not place tests in a module (*namespace*) since tests live outside your application and test its behaviors from the outside. You also don't have to worry about collisions with RSpec since it uses a functional DSL instead of creating test classes.

Comment: We refactored all of your specs to it after we started using the rubocop! :D I'll try your answer!  Thanks!